# Email Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work on a regular expression I've found and make it work with my requirements.  I have already modified the regular expression slightly to suit some of my requirements.  However, I need help to implement some of the conditions. The email is divided into 3 parts:

- the local part (before the last `@`);
- the last `@` symbol; and
- the domain part (after the `@`).

The regular expression that I have so far is:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9!#\$%&\'\*\+-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]{1,64})@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

The local part of the email address shall only contains the following special characters: `. " ( ) , : ; < > @ [ \ ]`.

An `.` in the local part of the email address should not be the first or last characters of the local part.

The condition for `( ) , : ; < > @ [ ]` to be displayed in the local part of an email address is `( ) , : ; < > @ [ ]` shall be contained between quotation marks.

In the local part of the email address, `"` and `\` shall be preceded with a backslash (i.e. `\"` or `\`).

Each part of the domain shall be separated by a period, and the domain part of an email shall be less than 256 characters.

Comment: Have you done any research before starting building your own?

Comment: Yet another email regex!

Comment: I wouldn't trust complex email regexes, most of them will surely leave some email out, IMO best regex is `/[^@]+@[^@]/`

Comment: Yes I have used the below mentioned regex for reference and modified it to suit my requirements                                         var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

Comment: I think you just need to take that complex RE and replace `.+` with the character set that you allow between quotes.

Comment: @elclanrs What you say is so true. In fact, valid emails can even contain more than one @ sign! (The domain comes after the last @ sign, not after the only @ sign.) For instance, "()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org is a valid email!

Comment: @Joseph Myers: actually elclanrs has a valid point - regex may give false positive results, but not return false negatives ever. So that you could make slower but the most accurate check with MTA

Comment: Updated re /^([a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?\^_`{\|}~\\".]*\\"[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?^_`{\|}~;,:<>()@\[\].]*\\"[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?^_`{\|}~\\".]*|[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?^_`{\|}~\\".]*\\'[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?^_`{\|}~;,:<>()@\[\].]*\\'[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?^_`{\|}~\\".]*|[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\\'*+\-\/=?^_`{\|}~\\".]{1,64})@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}))$/;